# NHibernate mapping to a 'denormalized' table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following object model (based on a legacy table structure that I can't change).

```
public class Store
    Contact BillingContact {get;set;}
    Contact SetupContact {get;set;}
    ISet<Contact> Contacts {get;set;}
```

In this scenario, when I create a new Store, I also add a new contact to the Contacts list.  I also want to set that contact to be the reference on the BillingContact and the SetupContact.  Then save the lot as a single transaction.  If I save the store without setting the Reference to BillingContact and SetupContact, everything is fine.  But when I set those properties, NHibernate tries to do an Update after the Insert to update the references and I get an error because the Store hasn't actually been inserted yet.

It looks like I may have to use a trigger or stored proc, but I'm hoping there is an NHibernate way.

The SQL being run is

```
INSERT INTO CONTACTS (Id, CompanyId, Name, etc.) Values (1234, NULL, "My Contact", etc.)  NOTE: 1234 was retrieved from a sequence
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO company (Id, BillingContactId, SetupContactId) Values (8946, 1234, 1234)
```

Then - Error is because of this

```
UPDATE CONTACTS SET CompanyId=8946  WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 1234 AND TimeStamp = xxx
```

Since the insert has not been committed the final statement fails.

The error is 
    Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) [Customer#1234]

Comment: Can you include the Sql nHibernate's running, your save code and the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the cascade for those references to Save-Update. This means, when you save or update an entity, it will save the references "by cascade".

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started

In the **Mappings** section there's an example with cascade.

Comment: both references are set to SaveUpdate.  I believe the problem is because I'm also adding it to the collection.